# fopen to add variable to file

Tags: php, fopen

I am creating an installer for my product that allows the developer to install the software. There is a configuration php file which I am opening in the same directory that the class exists which works fine.

```
class Package {
    private $_config;
    public function __construct($dsn,$user,$pass) {
        $this->_config = fopen('Config.php', 'w') or die("Unable to find Config file");
        [...]
```

However, when I want to then add the connection details to the file like so:

```
fwrite($this->_config, "$con = ['$dsn','$user','$pass'];");
fclose($this->_config);
```

the configuration file looks like this:

```
 = ['val', 'val', 'val']; // where val is the actual value of $dsn, $user, $pass
```

How can I achieve the file to look like this?:

```
$con = ['val', 'val', 'val'];
```

Never really used a file to store information, only databases so I'm new to the concept.

Comment: Use single quotes around the string, rather than double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use double quotes --"--, because they evaluate "$con" to empty string
Try this:

```
fwrite($this->_config, '$con' . " = ['$dsn','$user','$pass'];");
```

Comment: Always wondered why people used single quotes over double quotes sometimes, now I understand. Also, this worked - the output is as I desired. Appreciated! +1 for explanation on quotes too. (I'll mark when I can).